# Trouble adding externally hosted images on emails

Tags: marketing-cloud, images

I am really struggling with adding externally hosted images to emails. I don't have strong coding skills and I am just starting out with AMPscript but the syntax I am finding is all to call items within Marketing Cloud. I don't have Service Cloud or Sales Cloud.

My question is, how do I add externally hosted images into my emails that will render a unique image and link to each subscriber? Links to images and image hyperlinks will be stored in the data extension.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this AMPScript 101 reference:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/AMPscript101.htm

Essentially, you are just going to use AMPScript to read the image Url from your data extension into an html `<img />` tag's `src` within your email. Something like:

```
< img src="%%= v(@imageUrl) =%%" >< /img >  (minus the spaces before/after the < >)
```

Comment: You should remove the spaces between = and ()