# Rendering Image using data in my Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-template, dataextensions, html, images

I have a Data Extension in which I have the path a different path for each image in the row. I  am trying to pull this data in my email using an image block. How can I do it?

Should I be using image block here or an HTML block?

Answer (score 0):

Basic AmpScript will get you there.

You can do it in either an image or an HTML block with some simple html.

An example can be found in this topic:

[Trouble adding externally hosted images on emails](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/253153/trouble-adding-externally-hosted-images-on-emails/253164#253164)

Comment: I am trying to use Image Block and in the URL section I am adding the URL as https://image.s7.sfmc-content.com/lib/fe921373776d027c74/m/1/%%Image_Name%% , where "Image_Name" is the field name on the Data Extension. But I am getting an error in preview section.

Comment: The error is: HTML Version
Personalization error: The personalization string "" was not found in the following data extension(s).
 To fix the problem, please try the following:
 - Make sure that there is not a space or typo within the personalization string in your email. For example, check and correct any spaces between percent signs (%%)
 - Verify that the field containing the personalization string value is in all data extensions used.
 - Correct the HTML Body of your email.